# How to get the original post_id of a static home page?

Tags: homepage

I can't figure out how to get the original post_id of a specific page if that page has been set as the static posts page of the blog.

I have a page that normally has a post_id of 95, but as soon as I set it to the static posts page, it returns a post_id of 0 and it's causing me lots of headaches.

How can I retrieve the original post_id - which *is* stored in the DB because it comes right back if I make it not the static posts page any longer.

Comment: Try global $post, and then $post->id.

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I hadn't tried that before.  Interestingly, it DOES return me a post_id however it's not the right one!  Instead of the expected id of 95, I get id of 336 which is a completely different post.  Anyone have any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the id of the posts page is:

```
$posts_page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```

the conditional tag for the posts page would be: `is_home()`

edit:
the id of the static front page is:

```
$front_page_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't at all related to my question.  I need to know how to get the original post_id of the home/posts page, not to tell if it IS the home/posts page in the first place.

Comment: Oops, I stand somewhat corrected as I misunderstood.  This DOES return the original post_id of the posts page, which is half the battle!  But it does not return the original post_id of the home page.  So thank you very much for this, I just need this one last piece... anyone know how to get the original post_id of the home page?

Comment: afaik, you didn't ask for the static front page id - now edited into my answer.

Comment: Yep thanks, I had JUST figured this out a few minutes ago.  Unfortunately neither is returning anything for some strange reason: 
`if(is_home()){
  $postid = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
 }elseif(is_front_page()){
  $postid = get_option('page_on_front');
 }`
$postid comes up empty every time.  Any idea why?

Comment: if neither is set in 'settings -> reading' both `get_option()` return nothing. where exactly have you used the code?

Comment: But both are in fact set.  The problem is the is_home and is_front_page checks, both are failing.  The get_option works fine without those checks.

Comment: where are you using the code? does `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` work as expected?

Comment: No neither works at all, that seems to be the final issue.  I know they only work after the 'init' hook, and I have them firing in 'wp' so I expect that they should work... right?

Comment: OK WTF... suddenly it's working in 'wp' and I have no idea why.  sooo... I think I have what I needed, thanks Michael for all your answers!

Comment: Sorry, still one remaining problem:  is_front_page() is returning true, for BOTH the posts page AND the front page.  So I'm unable to check for one or the other.  Does it only work within certain hooks?

EDIT:  Just found this... sounds like I may be out of luck with this approach! http://nspeaks.com/1069/difference-between-is_home-and-is_front_page/