# How to get the true permalink of the static home page?

Tags: homepage, site-url, options

I asked a very similar question earlier today (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30392/how-to-get-the-original-post-id-of-a-static-home-page) and thought I had the answer, but now it appears otherwise.

If I have a post/page with the original permalink of `http://mydomain.com/blog/my-post/` for example, and I set that as the static home page of the blog, I am unable to get the original permalink of that page when I visit it, since WP only returns the root (`site_url()` essentially) permalink and redirects me there, since it is now set as the home page.

How can I retrieve the ORIGINAL permalink? `get_option('page_on_front')` doesn't work because it will just return the blog root url, such as `http://mydomain.com/blog/`.  I need to fetch the full original unaltered permalink of the currently-set static home page.

Hope that's clear... thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Wow. I mistyped a bunch the first time around. Hopefully nobody read that. All corrected now. /edit

I went code spelunking... :)

Short version, the workaround would be this:

```
<?php 
    $front_page_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
    $my_permalink = _get_page_link( $front_page_id ); 
?>
```

If you look into link-template.php in the WordPress core, you can kind of trace the path that happens. Calling the_permalink() leads to get_page_link(), which returns the permalink of the post/page ID you pass it. However, one of the checks that get_page_link() does is to see if the requested ID is currently set as 'page_on_front'. If it is, a static value of '/' is returned as the permalink. If it's not, the function _get_page_link() is called instead. Note the underscore on the front of the function.

In order to solve the issue, I cut past the_permalink() and get_page_link() and went straight to _get_page_link().

There may be some security issue or reason for this behavior to be default that I'm not aware of, but it works...

Comment: Holy cow... way to go hunting!  Let me see if this is the answer it appears to be for me and I'll report back shortly!

Comment: SO SWEET... This is exactly what I was after.  Nice of it to be so deeply buried!  ;)  Thanks for the help, I'd upvote you if I had enough rep here!

Comment: No problem. This is a great way to learn new stuff. :)